# Solving the 2D heat eqn with a rastering q term

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm brand new to Mathematica so please forgive my lack of knowledge, I'm trying to learn it for my current internship! I'll try give some background to what I'm doing and where I could do with some help :)

So, I've been tasked with finding the temperature distribution over a lead target [both circular and rectangular targets] that is being cooled by a copper frame kept at 265K and subjected to a 220MeV electron beam from an onsite accelerator. 
I have so far had "reasonable" results from solving the steady state 2D heat equation using a simple Gaussian source term (q) as a point source to input how much power is being dissipated in the target and a simple dirichlet BC keeping the outside temp at 265K. Also assuming the target is thin enough to call 2D.
[image: Code]

```
δ = ImplicitRegion[-b/2 <= x <= b/2 && -h/2 <= y <= h/2, {x, y}];

Γ = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 265, -b/2 <= x <= b/2],
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 265, -h/2 <= y <= h/2]};

q = NewTotalPowerr (1/((Sqrt[2 Pi])*sigmax*sigmay))
*(Exp[-((x - mux)^2 + (y - muy)^2)/(2*sigmay*sigmax)]);

pde = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == q/k};

uif = NDSolveValue[{pde, Γ}, u, 
{x, y} ∈ Ω];
```

This is my first attempt so now I'm trying modify the model to make it more realistic, obviously there's loads I haven't taken into consideration here!

So to start, in real life a point source melts the target.
So I'd like to somehow change my Gaussian source to a rastering one, a probability distribution that is more likely to place heat at the edges than the middle. By this I mean if my target was a 15mmx15mm square then the raster would cover an area of say 5mmx5mm rather than focussed on a 50 micrometer point.

The new PDF (I believe) is that of a sine wave:

```
q[x_,y_]:=Power*(1/Pi^2) ((1/Sqrt[1-x^2])(1/Sqrt[1-y^2])
```

My problem at the moment is that just inputting this into the code above (with the same heat input term) yields undesired results. The two distributions are: 
[image]

Is there a way of specifying that the q raster term should only act on a specified region but the pde would be solved over the whole area?
Is there another much better way of tackling this problem?

Any help would be superb thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome! Please post code in textual form as well, not only screenshots. This helps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ah sorry about that! Did it there, although couldn't figure out how to input symbols? Like Omega? Oh well, still makes sense, I think haha?